# What's the meaning of & after identifier name followed by () in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading an article about mock and fake object from Unity folks and then I saw this code:

```
FAKE_FUNCTION(GetScriptingManager, ScriptingManager&());
```

FAKE_FUNCTION macro is defined as:

```
#define FAKE_FUNCTION(functionName, signature) \
    FAKE_FUNCTION_IMPL(functionName, functionName, signature)
```

And FAKE_FUNCTION_IMPL is defined as:

```
#define FAKE_FUNCTION_IMPL(localName, functionName, signature) \
    struct __Fake ## localName : public ::testing::FakeFunction<signature> \
    { \
        __Fake ## localName() \
            : ::testing::FakeFunction<signature>(#functionName) {} \
    }; \
    __Fake ## localName localName
```

What's the meaning of ScriptingManager&()? I understood that's the argument of a template but I can't recall seeing such construct in C++.

Comment: It's a type, a zero argument function returning a reference to a Scripting Manager.

Comment: That macro takes function `ScriptingManager& GetScriptingManager()` with name `GetScriptingManager` and signature `ScriptingManager& ()`.